# How to rename specific files in a folder?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, rename

I'm now working on Mac Mountain Lion. I have a folder with about one thousand files whose names are like these:

```
file_1.png
file_2.png
file_3.png
file_4, word_abc.png
file_5.png
file_6, word_xyz.png
...
file_n.png
```

Now I want to select all the files with `,` and remove everything between `,` and `.png` including `,` so that the files appear as:

```
file_1.png
file_2.png
file_3.png
file_4.png
file_5.png
file_6.png
...
file_n.png
```

I have no idea what and how to do but manually rename these files. I wonder if there are any "automatic" ways to deal with this problem. Can you give a little help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should look into bash/shell scripting. [There are tons of great tutorials.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
for i in *,*; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/,.*/.png/')"; done
```